# Field Array push not able to focus next field?

Tags: redux-form

I'd like to know if is possible to focus the next field in `FieldArray` after a `fields.push('')`.

In my case, all time that a user put an empty space on an input a create a new on field array and want that this new one receives the focus.

Answer (score 0):

Your next field have is going to have name, so you can use the Focus action.

[Focus Action](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/#-code-focus-form-string-field-string-code-)